# How do I get from Tokyo to the Fuji Shibazakura Festival?

Tags: transit, japan, japan-rail

I'm trying to figure out how to get from Tokyo to the [Fuji Shibazakura Festival](http://www.shibazakura.jp/eng/aboutus/). As best I can tell from Google Maps I will need to take the [Oedo line](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Tokyo,+Japan/Kawaguchiko+Station,+Funatsu,+Fujikawaguchiko,+Yamanashi+Prefecture,+Japan/@35.594764,138.9532038,10z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x605d1b87f02e57e7:0x2e01618b22571b89!2m2!1d139.6917064!2d35.6894875!1m5!1m1!1s0x60196082ba487757:0x4d9403afbe34b4ed!2m2!1d138.7688431!2d35.4982343!2m5!5e0!5e1!5e2!5e3!8j1490320330!3e3) from Tokyo to Kawaguchiko, but I'm unclear on how to get from Kawaguchiko to the park. I'll have a Japan Railway pass, so preferably I'd like to take a train.

Comment: Have you read the "Access" page on the festival's website?

Comment: @fkraiem Yes. It is unclear to me how to get from Kawaguchiko to the park. That is why I am here.

Comment: What is unclear? Have you seen that the page contains the bus information between Kawaguchiko station and the festival site? (You do need to scroll down a bit.)

Comment: @fkraiem I specifically mention in my question that I would like to take the train. If you would like to answer that there is no train option so Ill have to take a bus that would answer my question. Also what would be good is if I can go directly from Tokyo to the park. Stopping through Kawaguchiko is not a must, its just the only way I can find.

Comment: Oh, right, reading your question again, I probably read it too hastily the first time...

Comment: Also, there is a big misunderstanding in the original question, as the Oedo line does not go to either Tokyo Station nor Kawaguchiko.  The google search in question shows Oedo from the city office to Shinjuku (which is about a 5 minute walk), and then a bus.  For future ref, "From Tokyo" when looking for a train route is a little like "From the US" when looking for an airfare.  You need to specify the originating station for the search to be of much use.

Answer (score 3):

The festival site is not accessible by train, so you have to take a bus (as indicated on the "Access" page of the festival's website), which will not be covered by your JR Pass.

By the way, note that Kawaguchiko station is not on a JR line, so trains to Kawaguchiko are not fully covered by your JR Pass either (specifically, the fare for the section between Otsuki and Kawaguchiko must be paid).